# Unable to select an option from drop down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have the following html:

```
<select id="80211Mode_5" onchange="ChangeWidthList('5')" name="80211Mode_5" sb="74332008" style="display: none;">
  <option value="802.11a">802.11a only</option>
  <option value="802.11n">802.11n only</option>
  <option value="802.11an">Mixed 802.11a/n</option>
  <option value="802.11ac">802.11ac only</option>
  <option value="802.11nac">Mixed 802.11n/ac</option>
  <option value="802.11anac">Mixed 802.11a/n/ac</option>
</select>
```

I want to loop through all the drop down option. I am able to select all the options from drop down box except `802.11n`.

When I try to select `802.11n`, I am getting `ElementNotVisibleException exception`. From the html  `802.11n` looks visible only. Why I am not able to select `802.11n` option particularly with below code:

```
def dlink_change_channel(self, channel):
    try:
        # Change channel in Dlink router
        self.login()
        self.browser_driver.find_element_by_id("menu_Settings").click()
        self.browser_driver.find_element_by_link_text("Wireless").click()
        self.browser_driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#RADIO_5GHz > div.advButton").click()
        self.browser_driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('sbOptions')[11].style.display='inline-block';")
        self.browser_driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('sbOptions')[11].scrollIntoView();")
        self.browser_driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('sbOptions')[11].click();")
        channel_xpath = "//a[@href="+"\'"+channel+"\'"+"]"
        print channel_xpath
        time.sleep(1)
        self.browser_driver.find_element_by_xpath(channel_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.browser_driver.find_element_by_id("Save_btn").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.browser_driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('sumbit_CheckData').click();")
        time.sleep(20)
        self.browser_driver.find_element_by_id("Confirm_btn").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.browser_driver.close()
```

I am passing `channel` to `dlink_change_channel` funtion from another function (I am passing `802.11a`, `802.11n` etc one by one from a loop)

Comment: try with findElements and using the xpath get all the elements value. After that loop through them. hope it helps.

Comment: The `<select>` tag doesn't get closed and I'm not sure if this is valid HTML at all. You tagged this [JavaScript] but you are not asking/giving any JavaScript code.

Comment: @A1rPun I got to know that execute_script executes java script code? I am new to html and selenium. Any javascript solution to this problem is also welcome.

Comment: Here is complete <select> tag

<select id="80211Mode_5" onchange="ChangeWidthList('5')" name="80211Mode_5" sb="74332008" style="display: none;">
        <option value="802.11a">802.11a only</option>
        <option value="802.11n">802.11n only</option>
        <option value="802.11an">Mixed 802.11a/n</option>
        <option value="802.11ac">802.11ac only</option>
        <option value="802.11nac">Mixed 802.11n/ac</option>
        <option value="802.11anac">Mixed 802.11a/n/ac</option>
    </select>

Comment: @Yogesh Alright,this `<select>` code makes more sense :) Maybe you could try this instead: `self.browser_driver.find_element_by_id("80211Mode_5").select("802.11n")`

Comment: it says :
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: Ah, you need to import `from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select` and the function I intended is `.select_by_value("802.11n")`

Comment: This code is working:
channel_xpath = "//select[@id='80211Mode_5']/option[@value="+"\'"+channel+"\'"+"]"
        time.sleep(1)
        self.browser_driver.find_element_by_xpath(channel_xpath).click()

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it as an answer and accept it so the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following code is working:

```
channel_xpath = "//select[@id='80211Mode_5']/option[@value="+"\'"+channel+"\'"+"]" 

time.sleep(1) 

self.browser_driver.find_element_by_xpath(channel_xpath).click()
```